# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'OracleConnection' Reuse of OracleConnection object

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection, oraclecommand

I would to reuse a OracleConnection object for more queries
so I wrote a simple class:

```
public static class DbConnectionsManager
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private static OracleConnection _dbConnection = null;


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="aConnectionString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static OracleConnection GetDatabaseConnection(string aConnectionString) 
        {
            try
            {
                if (_dbConnection == null)
                {
                    _dbConnection = new OracleConnection(aConnectionString);
                    _dbConnection.Open();
                    return _dbConnection;
                }

                if (_dbConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    _dbConnection.ConnectionString = aConnectionString;
                    _dbConnection.Open();
                    return _dbConnection;
                }

                if (!_dbConnection.ConnectionString.Equals(aConnectionString))
                {
                    _dbConnection.Close();
                    _dbConnection.ConnectionString = aConnectionString;
                    _dbConnection.Open();
                    return _dbConnection;
                }

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

in this way I can use the connection several times:

```
  using (OracleConnection connection = 
           DbConnectionsManager.GetDatabaseConnection(aDbConnectionString))
            {
                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
                command.CommandText = sql;

                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string myField = (string)reader["EXAMPLE"];
                    Console.WriteLine(myField);
                }
            }
```

When I call the method the first time everything works fine.
If I recall the method the static object is != null but the connection result closed!
I never close the connection!

When you try to reopen the connection I have this exception

```
....
if (_dbConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    _dbConnection.ConnectionString = aConnectionString;
                    _dbConnection.Open();
                    return _dbConnection;
                }
...
```

Error

```
Message = "Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'OracleConnection'."
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error says it's a disposed object. That means you need to remove the `using (` clause; this clause disposed your connection object and that's why you cannot use this object outside `using (`. That means you need to create a new object of class if you want to use it outside `using (`.

See:  [C# Using Statement](http://www.w3enterprises.com/articles/using.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer explains, the `using` clause isn't a natural fit for something you're wanting to *re-use*. However I had the same idea - I would still like to use this type of pattern to auto-open & auto-close the connection. If that is what you were hoping to do, then the key is that the object you are "using" cannot be the OracleConnection itself since you *do* want to reuse this, and "using" it will kill it. You really just want a new object which opens the connection on creation, and closes the connection on Dispose, and nothing more. This should do the trick (I am using it for my own purposes):

```
internal class OpenedContext : IDisposable
{
    private OracleConnection _connection;

    public OpenedContext(OracleConnection conn) {
        _connection = conn;
        if (_connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) _connection.Open();            
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (_connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) _connection.Close();
    }

}
```

And then in your example you could do something like...

```
            // Early on...
            OracleConnection _connection = DbConnectionsManager.GetDatabaseConnection(aDbConnectionString);

            // ... Later on, in various other calls ...
            using (new OpenedContext(_connection))
            {
                OracleCommand command = _connection.CreateCommand();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
                command.CommandText = sql;
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string myField = (string)reader["EXAMPLE"];
                    Console.WriteLine(myField);
                }
            }
```

Although it's goofy in a way, I definitely prefer setting up a pattern like this to always expecting future coders to manually "wrap" the re-open & re-close around every database call. It's more readable (or ignorable) and less risky (if you're greatly concerned about leaving the connection closed while idle).

Answer (score 0):

```
public OracleConnection GetConnection()
{

//Romove using(...) clouse 
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(_connSettings.GetConnectionString()))
{return con;}
```

The issue is inner using() clause problem.

```
using (OracleConnection con = GetConnection()){}
```